# Change "/bin/bash" in title of terminator and terminal?

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminator, window-title

I want to change the text `/bin/bash` to `root@kali` in the title of terminator and the terminal.  How may I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To generate a configuration file , run:

```
terminator -l init;
```

edit the `config` file:

```
nano ~/.config/terminator/config
```

Add a new title for the window / terminal:
e,g:

```
[global_config]
[keybindings]
[profiles]
  [[default]]
    cursor_color = "#aaaaaa"
[layouts]
  [[default]]
    [[[window0]]]
      type = Window
      parent = ""
      title = "window title here"
    [[[child1]]]
      type = Terminal
      parent = window0
      profile = default
      title = "terminal title here"
      command = ""
[plugins]
```

Alternative way: Use  <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + w</kbd> to set the window title and  <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + x</kbd> to set the terminal title.

Comment: I don't know if this is what the OP was looking for or not, but I had no idea these keyboard shortcuts even existed, and I've been using Terminator for a few years now! These are great, I just wish they were ~discoverable~ in the pointer secondary-click context menu (e.g., like toggling the scrollbar, changing profile, switching layout, etc.).

I suppose I'll still need to look into modifying my zsh config though to have the terminal or the window show the currently running command name (e.g., glances) without me manually setting a title.

Answer (score 0):

Executing this in your .bash_profile should do it:

```
echo -n "^[]2;root@kali^G"
```

Note the "^[" is escape.